# How do I create a shortcut in Pycharm to insert custom code?

Tags: pycharm

I'm using Pycharm to run code and take notes in Markdown for a class. I plan to upload these notes to Github later for quick review. The issue I have is that when I want to insert a code fragment in Markdown, I would need to type this:

````
```python3

```
````

This became very tedious as the class has a lot of different code examples. I want to be able to create a shortcut for it.

I tried going into `Settings > Keymap` but there was no option to create my own shortcut. The only thing I could do in there was modifying existing shortcuts to different keys. Is there a way for Pycharm to generate the above code snippet using a shortcut?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know the name of the functionality so I had problem searching for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a template.

Go to **Preferences** -> **Editor** -> **Live Templates**

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/tutorial-creating-and-applying-live-templates-code-snippets.html